# How do I fix intellisense in Vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have tried finding answers but none are helping so far.

It seems my VS code is not running correctly.

It does not autocomplete, does not show if something is missing a reference like controllerbase in this case, although it breaks the build:
[image: Controllerbase not showing as error]

It also does not pick up existing items to select while typing at all.

I have re installed VS code and of course restarted it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please add a language tag. C# I assume?

Answer (score 0):

You most to be sure that only have the plugins that you need some times many plugins can create bad behavior in vs code intellisense

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in vscode then I installed this extension "C# Namespace Autocompletion"
and it worked
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqXUs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRkPM.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).